# The name 'File' is defined in the libraries 'dart:html' and 'dart:io'

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

Does anybody know how to solve this error here's my code and the imports the error is in the "File" the error is as follows:

> The name 'File' is defined in the libraries 'dart:html' and 'dart:io'.

```
 @override
  State createState() => ChatScreenState(receiverId: receiverId, receiverAvatar: receiverAvatar);
}




class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen>
{
  final String receiverId;
  final String receiverAvatar;

  ChatScreenState({
    Key key,
    @required this.receiverId,
    @required this.receiverAvatar,
  });

  final TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();
  final FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool isDisplaySticker;
  bool isLoading;

  File imageFile;
  String imageUrl;

  String chatId;
  SharedPreferences preferences;
  String id;
  var listMessage;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    focusNode.addListener(onFocusChange);

    isDisplaySticker = false;
    isLoading = false;

    chatId = "";

    readLocal();
  }
```

I also imported this

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:file/file.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/FullImageWidget.dart';
import 'package:telegramchatapp/Widgets/ProgressWidget.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
```

[imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2HQN.png)
[Main sample of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVGPk.png)

Comment: Q: Have you tried qualifying the variable type with the package name, e.g. `io.File imageFile;`?

Comment: Use conditonal imports: https://medium.com/@dvargahali/dart-2-conditional-imports-update-16147a776aa8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please check you need `dart.html` or not.
If you need both packages, you can use a typecast operator `as`.

```
//import
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:html';


//Usage
io.File imageFile;
File htmlFile;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the unneeded import files, which will be shown with a blue underline.